# Series whose $a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

I was wondering if there are series whose $a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and diverges. I know one example, that is $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Slight modifications don't count, such as $a_n = \frac{c}{n}$ or $a_n = \frac{1}{n+k}$ where $c$ and $k$ belong to $o(n)$ (small o notation). These are effectively the same (at least the way I prove them). Is there a way to generalize all types of series which follow this criteria?

Comment: What about $a_n=\frac{1}{n\ln n}$?

Comment: How about $\frac1{\sqrt n}$, or $\frac1{\ln n}$?

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ converges iff $s>1$. Now modify.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-examples-of-slowly-divergent-series

Comment: Interestingly, in certain ways "almost all" series of positive terms with $a_n \rightarrow 0$ diverge. See this [18 September 2000 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=263888).

Comment: $c$ and $k$ belong to $o(n)$ sorry didn't mention in the question, i'll edit it